# antlr generates lexer but not parser

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to use Antlr v4 to generate a lexer and parser for a simple custom grammar. The issue is that when I run the Antlr .jar utility, it generates a Lexer file but not a Parser file too, as I think it should.

**Simple grammar**

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;         // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ;             // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

**Antlr tool**
Following along with these instructions: `https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tool-options.md`. The Java tool can be downloaded from `http://www.antlr.org/download/index.html` (I selected the `antlr-4.7-complete.jar`).

*Let's generate the lexer and parser*: `antlr.jar -o outDir -Dlangage=JavaScript -visitor -listener test.g4`

**Actual output**

- HelloLexer.js
- HelloLexer.tokens

**Desired output**

- HelloLexer.js
- HelloParser.js
- HelloListener.js
- HelloVisitor.js

I'd like the parser because once I have lexed the input, I want to parse and generate a tree which I can then traverse, as illustrated in this tutorial:

```
 var input = "your text to parse here"
 var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
 var lexer = new MyGrammarLexer.MyGrammarLexer(chars);
 var tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
 var parser = new MyGrammarParser.MyGrammarParser(tokens);
 // ^ [!] notice here how I don't have an analogous "HelloParser.js" to run my tokens through!
 parser.buildParseTrees = true;
 var tree = parser.MyStartRule();
```

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-do-i-run-the-generated-lexer-andor-parser

*How do I get the Antlr tool to generate the HelloParser.js file I want?* Right now it is only generating the Lexer, and the tutorials I have followed (links above) do not have any details for the situation I am in.

Comment: Could it be that you confuse JavaScript with Java?

Comment: On face value I see that using the Java tool to generate JavaScript may look strange, but according to [Antlr - How to create a lexer or parser](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md#how-to-create-a-javascript-lexer-or-parser) I need to create the lexer and parser before continuing to the next step of reading input and eventually using its syntax tree.

Comment: Did you eventually get an error from ANTLR? Your approach is totally correct, so I think there might be something that caused ANTLR to abort the generation. As a test try a different target (e.g. C++) to see if there's something with the JS target that causes the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by re-trying the Antlr tool (Java/.jar), but being extra-certain the `CLASSPATH` on Windows was being set correctly.

Following the [Getting started for Windows](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md#windows) doc, the `CLASSPATH` environment variable has to be set to include the Jar file's path. I originally did this using the `System Properties > Environment Variables` window, but for some reason it wasn't being registered (I've re-checked for typos and still see no issue).

Next time around I run the command `SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Javalib\antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%` manually and the lexer *and* parser are now being generated.

So the issue is that if `CLASSPATH` is set incorrectly, the Java tool silently fails. Without any warnings or errors, it was difficult to diagnose the error.

Comment: add option "-encoding UTF8" for UTF-8 .g4 files